# Вопрос по Java Applet

Tags: applet, java

Никогда не работал с апплетами, но вот сейчас появилась идея требующая "толстого" клиента (с поддержкой захвата звука и приема файлов для анализа) а значит нужно использовать либо апплет, либо JavaFX. До выхода версии 2.0 JavaFX не вижу смысла начинать на нем проект.

Я помню, что раньше апплеты встраивали в страницу тегом <applet...>, но вроде сейчас что-то поменялось, или нет?

Будет ли работать апплет, если к jar'у подключаются сторонние библиотеки, которые хранятся в папке lib, например?

И вообще как сейчас обстоят дела у апплетов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас две альтернативы. Использовать Java Web Start и тогда приложение будет запускаться со страницы и работать будет в своём окне, либо использовать JNLP для описания апплета. JNLP - это специальный XML-файл содержащий описание Java-приложения. Он используется для Java Web Start и может быть использован для апплетов.

Прочтите [тут об апплетах и JNLP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jnlp-136707.html).

Вот пример с этой же страницы.

HTML:

```
<applet id="jake2Applet" width="800" height="600"
    archive="CompatibilityApplet.jar"
    code="CompatibilityApplet">

    <param name="jnlp_href" value="jake2applet.jnlp">
    <param name="image" value="ajax-loader.gif">
    <param name="boxborder" value="false">
    <param name="centerimage" value="true">
    <param name="boxbgcolor" value="#000000">
    <param name="boxfgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    <!-- Require our own JVM instance for better robustness -->
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
    <!-- Parameters for the backward compatibility applet -->
    <param name="compat_bgcolor" value="#000000">
    <param name="compat_fgcolor" value="#ffffff">
</applet>
```

Тут видно, что он ссылается на JNLP. А вот сам JNLP, который описывает необходимые jar'ы и внешние библиотеки (JOGL в данном случае):

```
<jnlp href="jake2applet.jnlp">
    <resources os="Windows">
        <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
    </resources>
    <resources>
        <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.4+"/>
        <jar href="jake2.jar" main="true"/>
        <extension name="jogl"
            href="http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-webstart-current/jogl.jnlp" />
        <extension name="joal" href="http://download.java.net/media/joal/webstart/joal.jnlp" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
        name="Jake2"
        main-class="jake2.Jake2Applet"
    <!-- Overridden by the web page -->
        width="100" 
        height="100">
    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: 2 ХэшКод: я обнаружил серьёзную уязвимость в парсере. Куда мне писать о ней?

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Пишите нам на webmaster@hashcode.ru.